# Preserving PHP $this inside of foreach loop with ordered array of methods

Tags: php, oop, class, multidimensional-array, scope

I have the following PHP class which contains many other app-centric functions beside `my_new_iterative_function()` but when I enter the `foreach` the scope of `$this` (which I *need*) becomes invalid because of context.  What is the correct way to pass the `$this` so that it is valid inside of `method_foo` and `method_bar`.

NOTE: This is part of a more complex issue, and the `$fallback_order` executes functions in the default sequence, but the `my_new_iterative_function()` needs to accept an array to control order of execution (which is the purpose of the `$order_functions` array.

```
class Foo {
    public function my_new_iterative_function(array $fallback_order = array('method_foo', 'method_bar')) {

        $order_functions = array(
            'method_foo' => function(){
                // need to access $this
            },
            'method_bar' => function(){
                // need to access $this
            },
        );

        foreach ( $fallback_order as $index => $this_fallback ) {
            $order_functions[$this_fallback]();
        }
    }
}
$instance_of_foo->my_new_iterative_function(); 
$instance_of_foo->my_new_iterative_function([ 'method_bar', 'method_foo', ]);
```

Comment: Can't test this as I am at work and we aren't on the version of PHP that supports this, but try defining the functions as `'method_foo' => function () use ($this) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is to pass `$this` in as an argument:

`$order_functions[$this_fallback]($this);`

Then you would need to:

```
$order_functions = array(
            'method_foo' => function($myObj){
                // use $myObj $this
            },
            'method_bar' => function($myObj){
                // user $myObj instead of $this
            },
        );
```

No matter what you do you cant actually use `$this` inside those functions like you are inside the class instance because they aren't part of the class instance. So you'll need to make sure you have public accessors of some sort for all the properties or functions you need to use from the instance within those functions.

Comment: I have to accept this answer because you correctly anticipated the issue - I need access to other non-public properties of the `Foo` class, which is the reason that I'll need to approach this completely differently.

Answer (score 3):

you cant have `$this` in those functions because they don't belong to the foo class. They are just anonymous functions called by the foo class. If you need to access members of your class from within the anonymous function you should just pass `$this` to it like so:

```
    $order_functions = array(
        'method_foo' => function($obj){
            // need to access $this using $obj instead
        },
        'method_bar' => function($obj){
            // need to access $this using $obj instead
        },
    );

    foreach ( $fallback_order as $index => $this_fallback ) {
        $order_functions[$this_fallback]($this);
    }
```

Comment: There's really no way to do something like `$that = $this;`?  `$this` is valid before and after `$order_functions` surely there is a way to pass it to the array of methods...

Comment: You are passing `$this` to the method when you call it like `$order_functions[$this_fallback]($this);`

Answer (score 0):

the only way I see is passing `$this` to the functions

```
$order_functions = array(
    'method_foo' => function(Foo $foo){
        $foo->somePublicFunction();
    },
);

$order_functions[$this_fallback]($this);
```

but then you can only call public functions on the Foo instance... dunno if that fits your needs.